# why can't I specify a shade of color or color parameters in the fillcolor parameter of graphviz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, dot2tex

I am trying the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[pdf]{graphviz}

%%% Helper code for Overleaf's build system to
%%% automatically update output drawings when
%%% code in a \digraph{...} is modified
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\addFileDependency}[1]{% argument=file name and extension
  \typeout{(#1)}
  \@addtofilelist{#1}
  \IfFileExists{#1}{}{\typeout{No file #1.}}
}
\makeatother
\xpretocmd{\digraph}{\addFileDependency{#2.dot}}{}{}



\begin{document}
    
\digraph[scale=0.5]{abc}{rankdir=LR; a->b
a [style=filled,fillcolor=blue]
b [style=filled,fillcolor=blue!10];}

\end{document}
```

it doesn't work unless I remove the "!10", or if it does, it doesn't show a lighter shade of blue. I also cannot specify colors in the same way I can with tikz, only through names. Why is that?